# Pass a components boolean variable as parameter in click method Angular

Tags: angular, variables, parameters

Is it possible to pass a `boolean` variable in a method like this :

```
(click)="toggleView(isFontSpecs)"
```

The method is declared this way in the class:

```
toggleView(clickedItem: boolean){
    clickedItem = !clickedItem;
  }
```

Because this way neither variable change in the log.

Comment: No, JavaScript is not pass-by-reference. Just write `(click)="isFontSpecs=!isFontSpecs"`. If that results in too much repetition, consider putting your boolean variables in an array.

Comment: @Clashsoft Thanks i got to this solution earlier which is really good. In the other hand it's sad you can't edit variables this way.

Comment: when you want to change a variable of the component use this: `toggleView(clickedItem: boolean){ this.clickedItem = !this.clickedItem;}`, else only you're changing the "local" variable "clickedItem"

Comment: @Eliseo This is  incorrect. It shows error: ` Property 'clickedItem' does not exist on type <ComponentName>`

Comment: @gCorrect, when you use in .html `toggleView(isFontSpecs)` you're calling the function with the value true (if your variable defined in your .ts isFontSpecs is true) or false (in the other case). Inside your function, the variable "clickedItem" (it's a local variable) get the value. if you make "clickedItem=!clickedItem", your **local** variable change his value. When the function finished, the local variable is removed from the memory. You has do nothing. :(. Remember that a variable simple -a bool, a number or a string- pass "as value", not by reference

Comment: If you want to change the variable "isFontSpecs", inside the function you use `this.isFontSpecs=!this.isFontSpecs`

Answer (score -1):

Please let me know if you are looking for something else entirely...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xw1b5k?file=src/main.ts

If you already know then you can simply pass it in the click event where you are calling the method.

Component HTML file:

```
<a (click)="method(true)">
   Learn more about Angular 
</a>
```

Component TS file:

```
method(value: boolean) {
  console.log(typeof value);
}
```